# Is it possible to create <a href...</a> for uploaded file with php?

Tags: php, upload, hyperlink

what I am trying to achieve is that I want to create a link for downloading file somewhere on the webpage for the newly uploaded file via php
the php code looks like this:
    `

```
    $target_path = "uploads/";      
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];      
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);      
$allowed =  array('gp5','gp4' ,'gp3');  
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];  
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {  
    echo 'not a valid file extension';  
}   
else {  
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']);  
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {  
            echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name'])." has   been uploaded";  
        } else {  
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";  
        }  
}
```

`

Comment: Yes, of course it is. Just copy the file to a publicly accessible path (or make sure `$target_path` is reachable) and link to it. Or, add a publicly reachable PHP file which does some authentication and then streams the file from a non-publicly reachable location.

Comment: See https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20download%20links%20for%20uploaded%20files for similar questions. It appears you'd need a tutorial otherwise.

Comment: @mario, neither google.com nor stackoverflow doesn't have the answer for this question

Comment: Oh I'm pretty certain we have all variations of `glob("uploads/*")` covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming target path is somewhere in the `web root`, you can simply do this within the `success` portion of the `if` statement for `move_uploaded_file`:

```
echo '<a href="'.$target_path.'">'.$file.'</a>';
```

---

EDIT

---

Turns out what you want is a list of the uploaded files:

```
echo '<ol>';
$files=scandir('uploads');
foreach($files as $file)
{
    if($file=='.'||$file=='..') continue;

    echo '<li><a href="uploads/'.$file.'">Click Here to Download</a></li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
```

---

EDIT: From the comments, you wanted everything to be in a single page:

Combine upload.php and example.html into example.php. Have the form submit to itself. That way you never need to go to another page.

Comment: and how can I put somewhere specific ? Like in an unsorted row or smt like that ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "unsorted row", but if you want to move to to a different location when you call `move_uploaded_file`, just set `$target_path` to be something else before calling `move_uploaded_file`. It doesn't actually have to be the same name that it originally was.

Comment: what I mean is that I have a form in my html page that starts the php code, which is in another external file, what I need is to create a link to a  newly created file somewhere around that form

Comment: You mean you want a list of all uploaded files, regardless of who uploads them, to appear below the form?

Comment: Yes, for now it would be enough

Comment: erm... not what I meant... When I click "upload" it redirects to the upload.php, and your answer prints those links in the upload.php, but I need to access the previous page example.html and make a link there

Comment: Combine upload.php and example.html into example.php. Have the form submit to itself. That way you never need to go to another page.